# How do I get column names under a barplot from aggregated data using multiple variables?

Tags: r, aggregate, bar-chart, legend

I have a data file with tree data called ufc.csv, and after reading it in with a `read.csv()` function, I used an aggregate function to get the means of tree diameter (Dbh) and tree height (Height) sorted by species name (Species):

```
ufcmeans = aggregate(x = ufc[,4:5], by = ufc[3], FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The first row was empty, so, after removing it with ufcmeans[-1,], I get this data frame:

```
Species Dbh Height
2 DF 383.7143 254.3036
3 ES 403.3333 280.0000
4 F 372.0000 270.0000
5 FG 381.5000 275.0000
6 GF 351.5838 242.6522
7 HW 209.0000 198.0000
8 LP 232.8571 218.3333
9 PP 568.5000 330.0000
10 SF 136.4286 154.1000
11 WC 375.0757 234.8777
12 WL 340.0588 252.5714
13 WP 319.7273 251.3939
```

My goal is to make a barplot that has the mean values for Dbh and Height alternating and organized by Species with the Species names under each pair of columns (so first two columns are the first Dbh and Height means, and the name "DF" is under both of them, and so on).

At first I tried making ufcmeans into a matrix called meansmatrix with the `as.matrix()` function and then plugging it into a `barplot()` function, but I got an error saying this:

```
> barplot(meansmatrix, beside=TRUE, col=c("red","blue"))
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Next, I tried making a matrix without the species column, and I was able to get two barplots made on one graph, but the species names weren't on there (which made sense since I removed it), so I tried using a names.arg statement to include the Species name, but I got an error saying there weren't enough names.

How do I get the barplot I'm envisioning with the `barplot()` function?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
barplot(cbind(Dbh, Height) ~ Species, dat, beside=TRUE, legend.text=names(dat)[2:3])
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
                  Species Dbh Height
2 DF 383.7143 254.3036
3 ES 403.3333 280.0000
4 F 372.0000 270.0000
5 FG 381.5000 275.0000
6 GF 351.5838 242.6522
7 HW 209.0000 198.0000
8 LP 232.8571 218.3333
9 PP 568.5000 330.0000
10 SF 136.4286 154.1000
11 WC 375.0757 234.8777
12 WL 340.0588 252.5714
13 WP 319.7273 251.3939')
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the right output! Would I just replace 'dat' with as.matrix(ufcmeans)?

Comment: @robotnoises ufcmeans is enough, dat is also a data.frame. definitely read `?barplot`, it has a ton of options to fine tune the plot.